Continuous modification of tangent vector fields
Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $S^2$, and assume that there exists a continuous tangent vector field $F(x)$ defined on $\bar{\Omega}\neq S^2$ with $|F(x)|=1$ for all $x\in \bar{\Omega}$. Suppose a continuous vector field $G$ is given on $\partial \Omega$ with $|G(y)|=1$ for all $y\in \partial \Omega$. Can $F$ be continuously modified to a unit tangent vector field $F'(x)$ ($|F'(x)|=1$ for all $x\in\bar{\Omega}$) on $\bar{\Omega}$ such that $F'(y)\neq G(y)$ for all $y \in \partial \Omega$? In other words, does there exist a unit tangent vector field $F'$ on $\bar{\Omega}$ such that $F'$ is continuous and $F'-G$ does not vanish on $\partial \Omega$?

@ChristianRemling: $G$ is only defined on $\partial \Omega$ and not on $\bar{\Omega}$.

Think of $\Omega$ as an open set in the plane. If $F$, restricted to the boundary, has a different winding number than $G$, then all deformations of $F$ through unit vector fields still have that same winding number, and writing $F$ and $G$ as unit complex numbers $F=e^{if}$ and $G=e^{ig}$, we find that $e^{i(f-g)}$ has nonzero winding number, so equals $1$ somewhere on $\partial \Omega$. But then $F=G$ there.

Thank you, Ben. I just posted another related question. I would appreciate if you could take a look: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/468779/continuous-extensions-of-tangent-vector-fields
