Continuous extensions of tangent vector fields
Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $S^2$ with $\bar{\Omega}\neq S^2$. Suppose a continuous tangent vector field $G$ is given on $\partial \Omega$ with $|G(y)|=1$ for all $y\in \partial \Omega$. Does there exist a continuous tangent vector field $F$ on $\bar{\Omega}$ such that $|F(x)|=1$ for all $x\in \bar{\Omega}$ and $F-G$ does not vanish on $\partial \Omega$?

Is G also a tangent vector field, as F is?

@DanielAsimov Yes. I revised the question.

$F\neq G$ on $\partial \Omega$, or $F=G$?

@MarkGrant $F \neq G$ on $\partial \Omega$. Indeed if the result holds for $F=G$, then it would violate the hairy ball theorem.So we know that the result can no hold for $F=G$.

I claim that $F$ exists if and only if $G$ has zero winding number around the boundary of $\Omega$. I will only give a complete proof of one direction.
We can suppose that $\Omega$ is a plane domain, say in the complex plane.
Suppose that there is such an $F$. On the boundary of $\Omega$, the angle between $F$ and $G$ is positive and periodic (or is negative and periodic; it just isn't anywhere zero). So we can write $G=e^{i\theta}F$ on the boundary, with $0<\theta<2\pi$ a periodic function. We can then deform $G$ by a homotopy $H_t:=e^{i(t\pi+(1-t)\theta)}F$ since a convex combination of numbers between $0$ and $2\pi$ is also a number in that interval. So then $H_t\ne F$ for all $t$. We find that $F$ has the same winding number as $H_1=-F$, so $F$ has the same winding number as $G$. By the Poincare--Hopf theorem, $F$ has winding number zero around the boundary of $\Omega$. So $G$ must as well.
Suppose that $\Omega$ has connected boundary. By a theorem of Whitney, maps from the circle to the circle have the same winding number just when they are homotopic. The proof again is that we write the maps as $e^{i\alpha}$ and $e^{i\beta}$, and then the winding number is
$$\frac{\alpha(2\pi)-\alpha(0)}{2\pi}.$$
If they have the same winding number, then
$$H_s(t):=e^{(1-s)\alpha(t)+s\beta(t)}$$
is a homotopy between them.
Hence we can take $G$ to be unit constant, and then extend as a constant function $F$ for a different unit constant.

Thank you, Ben. Does this proof imply that such extension exists if only if the winding number of $G$ is zero?

Minor correction: $G_1 = G$; it is $G_0$ that equals $-F$.
